# Convert elastic search query to nest AggregationDictionary

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a elastic search query that looks like this:

```
_search{
   "aggs": {
     "bodyTypeMinPrice": {
       "terms": {
        "field": "specification.bodyType"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "highest_price": {
          "max": {
        "field": "specification.price.dealerGrossPrice"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where I want the minimum price (specification.price.dealerGrossPrice) per bodytype (specification.bodyType).

How can i convert this query to a AggregationDictionary?

I am using nest 7.17.

This is what I have so far, but I have no idea how to put them together:

```
var aggregationDictionary = new AggregationDictionary();

var aggregationContainer= new AggregationContainer();

var term = new Term() { Field = new Field("specification.bodyType") };

var minAgg = new MinAggregation("minDealerGrossPrice", "specification.price.dealerGrossPrice");
```

Comment: You dont use any dataclass with your nest Client? 

Would be something like:
     AggregationContainerDescriptor<Specification> aggregationContainer = new AggregationContainerDescriptor<Specification>();
     aggregationContainer.Terms("bodyTypeMinPrice", t => t.Field(fi => fi.bodyType).Aggregations(ag2 => ag2.Max("highest_price", tt => tt.Field(F2 => F2.price.dealerGrossPrice))));